# How to change Sensor name of self developed Sonar plugin in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

after a while now I finished the development of my own SonarQube plugin nearly. How my plugin works and what it does is is not important so far.
I just want to change one last thing.

How can i modify the name of my Sensor? I mean that one which is shown in Jenkins (my build environment) when the Sensor gets used. I want to show there only "Sensor ProjectKeyChecker..." or something like that if it possible :)

Here is an example output of Jenkins:

```
[INFO] [15:12:27.723] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.projectkeychecker.ProjectKeyCheckerSensor@79aa11...
[INFO] [15:12:27.786] Project exists already on Sonar. Key check is unnecessary.
[INFO] [15:12:27.786] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.projectkeychecker.ProjectKeyCheckerSensor@79aa11 done: 63 ms
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you just have to implement the #toString() method.

Comment: could you please explain that a little bit more :)
I do not really know what you mean. 
Where must this method be implemented? Shell it return the name i want to see in my output?
Could you please give me a litte example with some more information? :)

Comment: Take a look at this class and its #toString() method: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sonar/reference/batch/ExampleSensor.java