# How to suppress execution of post-jobs when using BuildBreaker plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I developed a plugin for my company. The main work is done and the plugin itself works also fine for now.

All i have is kind of "aesthetics problems".

When a build job is finished without failure the console output tells me the following thing:
(just for the protocol: I'm using Jenkins to execute build jobs)

```
[...]
[INFO] [16:12:08.270] <- Clean snapshot 574387
[INFO] [16:12:08.723] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.projectkeychecker.ProjectKeyCheckerSensor
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Do you know how i can suppress that last info output?
It comes up with the BuildBreaker Plugin. I don't do anything here so I don't want to show this message in my output.

(for more context please browse [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690521/how-to-change-sensor-name-of-self-developed-sonar-plugin-in-jenkins/22788446?noredirect=1#comment34775558_22788446))

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i already mentioned: It comes up with the BuildBreaker Plugin.

When i told my class to extend BuildBreaker

```
public class MySensor extends BuildBreaker implements Sensor {
```

i had to implement the method executeOn

```
@Override
public void executeOn(Project arg0, SensorContext arg1) { }
```

and the method executeOn is activated as a PostJop... So i need to delete this method to avoid my problem.

SOLUTION:

1) Do not extend BuildBreaker anymore -> don't implement the method executeOn anymore

2.) Instead of using the Method "fail (String message)", which came also up with BuildBreaker use directly the command "throw new SonarException(String message);"(you will need to import org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException as well)

Thanks everyone, who read this.